# Implement an API OAuth call from a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, api, oauth

In the first step of an oauth call, when a Authorization Code is requested, the process requires a `redirect_uri` endpoint to be submitted along with a request. To this endpoint, the user is re-directed once the code is received.

What I'm struggling to understand is how this process would work when the call is originating from within a Windows Service.

**Bigger Picture:**

We are creating an app that integrates with a cloud based access-control system with our own software. By 'access-control' I just mean the type of system where you scan your access card against a door-reader to enter your office.  Our windows service will continually monitor the access-control server (in the cloud) for any access-events, and when it finds a new one, it will import that event into our database.

To interact with their database, the access-control parent company has provided an API that requires OAuth.  From all I can see, OAuth is meant to be consumed by a web-based app where both user-interaction and a UI are a forgone conclusion.  But, I am not picturing how to implement an OAuth process where there is no user, no UI, and no browser involved.

**Confession:**

I've never complimented an OAuth call before, so I could be over-thinking this, or missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience implementing OAuth on a Windows service, the process works the same, in which you still have to supply the correct `redirect_url`. I think the `redirect_url` is used to bind and validate your `client_id` (as mentioned in the RFC somewhere). Supplying the wrong/invalide `redirect_url` will deny authorization to the client. You only need to consume the `authorization code`, and use it to get the tokens. You will get the HTML document returned to you as part of the response after the request (that gets you the token). I'm still new at this, though, and this is only what I learned from my experience.